# "Output" equivalent for Intersystems Cache - Or how to output updated data?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I have the following query I need to run on my production data, but I would like to output the `id` column so that I have a record of the updated rows.  In MS SQL Server I can use `OUTPUT` but I can't find anything similar in the [intersystems-cache](/questions/tagged/intersystems-cache)  [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL).

```
UPDATE someTable as st
SET st.InActive = 1
WHERE st.ID IN (
        SELECT a.ID
        FROM someTable a
        natural join otherTable b
        WHERE b.EffectiveDate < '2016-09-15'
        ORDER BY a.ID Desc
)
```

Comment: By output you mean write to screen in some way?

Comment: Yes, much like `SELECT` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you looking for something like [RETURNING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) clause in PostgreSQL. 
Unfortunately InterSystems Caché does not have such functionality or similar.